# Transformers Longformer IndexError: index out of range in self

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

From Transformers library I use `LongformerModel, LongformerTokenizerFast, LongformerConfig` (all of them use `from_pretrained("allenai/longformer-base-4096")`).

When I do

```
longformer(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
```

I get such an error:

```
~/tfproject/tfenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_longformer.py in forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids, position_ids, inputs_embeds)
    177         if inputs_embeds is None:
    178             inputs_embeds = self.word_embeddings(input_ids)
--> 179         position_embeddings = self.position_embeddings(position_ids)
    180         token_type_embeddings = self.token_type_embeddings(token_type_ids)
    181 

~/tfproject/tfenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/tfproject/tfenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py in forward(self, input)
    112         return F.embedding(
    113             input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
--> 114             self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self):

~/tfproject/tfenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1722         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1723         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1724     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1725 
   1726 

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Online I found that this might mean that my input to the model has more tokens than the model's max input size.

But I have checked and all inputs have exactly 4098 tokens (which is the model max length of input size) (padding has been applied). Tokenizer has the same vocab size as the model.

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Maybe one of your `position_ids` is larger than `num_embeddings` in `position_embeddings` layer. In that case you have reindex your `position_ids`. Just a guess.

Comment: Your `token_type_ids` might have only 4098 unique values but torch will through this error if any of the `token_type_ids` is greater than 4098.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth, hi thanks for answering, I already managed to fix that. You are right, I had to reindex my `position_ids`. That was not `token_type_ids` problem because I manually set those to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by reindexing my `position_ids`.

When PyTorch was creating that tensor, for some reason some value in `position_ids` was bigger than 4098.

I used:

```
position_ids = torch.stack([torch.arange(config.max_position_embeddings) for a in range(val_dataloader.batch_size)]).to(device)
```

to create `position_ids` for the entire batch.

Bear in mind that it might not be the best solution. The problem might need some more debugging. But for a quick fix, it works.

Comment: What exactly is the val_dataloader a part of? I am trying to implement the same solution but am getting an error.

Comment: @JoeNordling, val_dataloader is an instance of `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.